# Read tab delimited file with unusual characters, then write an exact copy

Tags: r

### The problem

I have a tab delimited input file that looks like so:

```
Variable [1]    Variable [2]
111    Something
Nothing    222
```

The first row represents column names and the two next rows represents column values. As you can see, the column names includes both spaces and some tricky signs.

Now, what I want to do is to import this file into R and then output it again to a new text file, making it look exactly the same as the input. For this purpose I have created the following script (assuming that the input file is called "Test.txt"):

```
file <- "Test.txt"
x <- read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
write.table(x, file = "TestOutput.txt", sep = "\t", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

From this, I get an output that looks like this:

```
"Variable..1."  "Variable..2."
"1"    "111"    "Something"
"2"    "Nothing"    "222"
```

Now, there are a couple of problems with this output.

1. The "[" and "]" signs have been converted to dots.
2. The spaces have been converted to dots.
3. Quote signs have appeared everywhere.

*How can I make the output file look exactly the same as the input file?*

### What I've tried so far

Regarding problem number one and two, I've tried specifying the column names through creating an internal vector, `c("Variable [1]", "Variable [2]")`, and then using the `col.names` option for `read.table()`. This gives me the exact same output. I've also tried different encodings, through the `encoding` option for `table.read()`. If I look at the internally created vector, mentioned above, it prints the variable names as they should be printed so I guess there is a problem with the conversion between the "text -> R" and the "R -> text" phases of the process. That is, if I look at the data frame created by `read.table()` without any internally created vectors, the column names are wrong.

As for problem number three, I'm pretty much lost and haven't been able to figure out what I should try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the following input file as `test.txt`:

```
Variable [1]    Variable [2]
111 Something
Nothing 222
```

Where the columns are tab-separated you can use the following code to create an exact copy:

```
a <- read.table(file='test.txt', check.names=F, sep='\t', header=T, 
    stringsAsFactors=F)
write.table(x=a, file='test_copy.txt', quote=F, row.names=F, 
    col.names=T, sep='\t')
```

Comment: Nice. I'm paranoid, but I would prefer `TRUE` and `FALSE` to `T` and `F` here, just in case those variables get reassigned ...